# Issue with iOS 6 when using camera via input type file

Tags: html, ipad, web-applications

I´m writing a webapp for an ipad and on it I need to take a picture using the camera. My solution is using input type="file" but the problem is that when iOS brings up the camera it automatically changes the orientation. When I finish taking the picture and it returns to my app, the app is displayed on portrait mode, even though I'm holding the ipad on landscape mode. Is there a way to make the ipad not change orientation when invoking the camera?

Answer (score 0):

Today we encountered the same problem. Even worse if the device is locked in landscape mode, it is impossible to get it out of portret mode. The orientation of the page is changed directly after you press 'take image' button, even before the camera app is showing. We are still working out how to solve this but until now I think it is an Apple 'feature'.