# HTML5 camera input strange behaviour in fullscreen

Tags: html, ipad, camera, fullscreen

I´m writing a webapp for an iPad with HTML5, JavaScript and jQuery. My users need to take pictures with the build-in camera. For that reason I am using input type="file". This works great in different browsers (Chrome/Safari Mobile) but the problem is that when I add my app to the homescreen and take a photo in lanscape fullscreen mode- iOS brings up the camera from the wrong side. To be clearer iPad in landscape mode camera slides in from the left side(should be from the bottom). It behaves like it was called from portrait mode and the picture has a dark part on the left side. The camera window automatically changes the orientation - I debugged it - twice (0°/-90°). When I finish taking the picture and return to the app it is displayed in portrait mode, even though holding it on landscape mode. And additionally the screen is somehow locked. Thsi behaviour doesen't occure holding the iPad in portrait mode. Anyone an idea how to solve this strange behaviour? I found that [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16715943/issue-with-ios-6-when-using-camera-via-input-type-file) but no answers...